# ffmpeg drawtext and watermark only creates watermark but no text

Tags: ffmpeg, watermark

If I try to add a text and a watermark at the same time, only the watermark shows.

```
ffmpeg -i i.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -f mp4 
  -vf drawtext="fontfile=/[...]/share/fonts/freefont-ttf/FreeSans.ttf
    :text='TESTING':fontcolor=black@1.0:fontsize=36:x=00: y=40" 
  -vf 'watermarkfile.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=0:0 [out]' o.mp4
```

(All in one line. Here I have added line breaks for clarity.)

If I remove the watermark part, the text appears instead, as follows:

```
ffmpeg -i i.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -f mp4 
  -vf drawtext="fontfile=/[...]/share/fonts/freefont-ttf/FreeSans.ttf
    :text='TESTING':fontcolor=black@1.0:fontsize=36:x=00: y=40" 
  o.mp4
```

But how can I get both text and watermark at the same time?

Comment: You should always also include the complete ffmpeg console output.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should perform the filtering in one [filtergraph](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtergraph-syntax-1):

```
ffmpeg -i i.mp4 -i watermarkfile.png -filter_complex \
"[0:v]drawtext=fontfile=/path/to/fonts/FreeSans.ttf:text='TESTING':fontcolor=black@1.0:fontsize=36:x=00:y=40[text]; \
[text][1:v]overlay[filtered]" -map "[filtered]" \
-map 0:a -codec:v libx264 -codec:a copy output.mp4
```

- Use `-filter_complex` instead of `-vf` with multiple inputs and/or outputs.
- You do not need to use the `movie` multimedia source filter.
- The audio can be [stream copied](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) instead of being re-encoded.
- See the [FFmpeg and x264 Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/x264EncodingGuide) for encoding suggestions.
- See the documentation on the [`drawtext`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext-1) and [`overlay`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay) video filters for more info.

Comment: Thanks. Here is a continuation of this question: http://superuser.com/q/706373/217699

Comment: How to add special character in my watermark text? Here I posted question. Please answer me - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38266469/ffmpeg-utf-8-special-character-not-working-in-video-watermark-text